# what is the X component of the point , where the spherical coordinates of point are (100,30,60)?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

The spherical coordinates of point are $(100,30,60)$,
what is the X component of the point

1. $30$
2. $43.3$
3. $50$
4. $75$

I know that in the spherical coordinates, $$x = r \sin(\theta) \cos(\phi),$$
so
$$x = 100 \sin(30) \cos(60) = 26.684892,$$
which is not in the choice list !

Comment: Check your calculator is working in the right mode. The angles given look to be in degrees.

Comment: Where did you get that $100 \sin(30) \cos(60) = 26.684892$, should not it be $25$ (if they are in degrees) or $94.1$ (if they are in radians)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me the angles are in degrees and you confused $\phi$ and $\theta$ values. The correct expression should be
$$
100 \sin\left(60 ^\circ\right) \cos\left(30 ^\circ \right) = 75
$$